# Prevent keypress to bubble to input in mousetrap

Tags: javascript, mousetrap

I am using mousetrap for capturing key presses. One of the shortcuts I want to define is to focus on an input.

`Mousetrap.bind('i', function() { $('.input').focus() });`

The focussing works fine, but the 'i' keypress also gets bubbled to the input, and with being focussed, the input also gets populated with 'i'.

Is there a way to prevent the 'i' from being written in the input?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right there [in the documentation](http://craig.is/killing/mice#api.bind.default):

> As a convenience you can also return false in your callback:
>
> ```
> Mousetrap.bind(['ctrl+s', 'meta+s'], function(e) {
>     _saveDraft();
>     return false;
> });
> ```
>
> Returning false here works the same way as jQuery's return false. It prevents the default action and stops the event from bubbling up.

So:

```
Mousetrap.bind('i', function() {
    $('.input').focus();
    return false;
});
```