# Keep Mousetrap Shortcut out of autoFocused Input when changing Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, mousetrap

I have a route which leads to a page with an input I want focused.

Using a Mousetrap shortcut to get there, puts the shortcut key into the input.

For example, a Shortcut "a" for appointments, renders the page with an "a" in the input field

is there a way i can prevent this?

I get this both with:

```
<input autoFocus />
```

and using a ref and focusing on didMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.input.focus();
}
render() {
    return <input ref={input => (this.input = input)} />;
}
```

here is a code sandbox showing both shortcuts (a/r)

https://codesandbox.io/s/0oll7jmxqn

help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found the answer from

[Prevent keypress to bubble to input in mousetrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087791/prevent-keypress-to-bubble-to-input-in-mousetrap?rq=1)

It is as simple as

```
return false;
```